# MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 (Windows)

Tags: mysql

I need to upgrade MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 on a Windows community server (install version).

Do I need to dump and import to 5.7 then to 8.0 ? or a simple dump of all databases from 5.6 is enough ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html

Comment: I have already read it, but i can't perfom an upgrade because it's not the same release, that's why i want to make a dump.

Comment: Upgrade from 5.6 to 5.7 and there are lot of 'administrative table' changes behind the scene that will hurt you if you try to skip this step.  The use the new MySQL shell (mysqlsh) and use the utility to double check setting between 5.7 and 8.0 for thinks like the use of reserved words and the like.

Comment: None backup is excess. It is better to make three dumps for nothing than not to make one-and face a problem.